# Linux Shell: Extract values separated by pipes from a file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have the following values in a file:

```
line 1: 31915
line 2: Salchipapa|papa|salchicha|aceite|queso
```

I need to get the values papa, salchicha, aceite, queso

that means that i have to get the values from the line 2, column 2 On.

Comment: Are there always 5 pipe-separated fields, or can there be more or less?

Comment: You are supposed to do your own homework

Comment: Whether this is a class assignment or not, what have you tried? A little bit of Google will give you the answer as the solution is very easy.

Comment: What is the desired output format? Should comma and space separate the values or just a comma or just a space? Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read them all into an array by changing `IFS` and keep them for future use.....

```
OIFS=$IFS; IFS='|'; array=($(sed '2q;d' "$filename")); IFS=$OIFS

echo ${array[0]}
Salchipapa

echo ${array[1]}
papa
```

That way you are not restricting yourself to an arbitrary 10 values and you also don't need to test for 'null' later because you know the number of elements in the array....

```
echo ${#array[@]}
5
```

So you just ....

```
for (( i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++ )); do echo ${array[$i]}; done
Salchipapa
papa
salchicha
aceite
queso
```

Comment: I love your answer. I learned a lot from it. Thank you. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Mission accomplished

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this and it worked:

```
     for i in {2..10}
     do
        ingName=$(sed -n 2p $filename | cut -d '|' -f $i)
     done
```

"sed -n 2p $filename" gets the second line of the file and then "cut -d '|' -f $i" gives me each ingredient separated by pipes. the number 10 indicates that there are maximum 10 ingredients, so later on in the code I validate that I worked only when the variable ingName is not null.

Comment: You should always quote filename variables like this: `"$filename"`. Note, that your solution will be pretty slow as it calls `sed` and `cut` for each iteration.

Comment: I found many options, also awk could be used instead of cut.

Comment: When you add more information to a post its better to edit your original post and keep all the information there so people can see it, rather than post it as a comment or an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the actual file's content is

```
31915
Salchipapa|papa|salchicha|aceite|queso
```

then you could use

```
awk -F '|' 'FNR == 2 { for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) print $i }' file
```

to print the fields from the 2nd field onwards from the second line, one word per line of output.

The following `sed` command would do the same:

```
sed '1d;2y/|/\n/;s/[^\n]*\n//' file
```

It does this by deleting the first line from the input, then changes all pipes to newlines, and deletes up to (and including) the first newline.

The pipeline

```
tail -n 1 file | cut -d '|' -f 2- | tr '|' '\n'
```

would produce the same output given the example data by picking out the last line with `tail`, extracting the fields from the 2nd onwards with `cut` and then changing all pipes to newlines.

A variation on the above:

```
tail -n 1 file | tr '|' '\n' | tail -n +2
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and it worked fine

```
awk 'NR==2{print $NF}' filename| awk -F "|" '{$1="";print $0}' |sed -r "s/^\s+//g"| perl -pne "s/ /\n/g"
```

output

```
papa
salchicha
aceite
queso
```